# Microservice, database relation and caching

Tags: database, redis, microservices

I am new at microservices that is why these two question bothering me.

if we have per database per microservice, for example, we have a service called **menu** which maintains creating and updating menus and we have another service, for example **user-access**, which checks user's access to menu. This two services have their own database.

Which approach is right? Calling **menu** service from **user-access**, or caching menus to **Redis** and calling requested menus from **Redis**? And what if i need to return menu name to **front-end** from **user-access** application.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microservice architecture may sound interesting on paper but is a lot more than that when it comes to implementing it.
Many developers face queries just like yours all the time, i.e about choosing the right pattern or flow of API calls.

I think the most simple and straight forward answer to this is that you should decide what is the correct approach depending on your applications needs. One may find your approach wrong or inefficient even though it may be perfect for you. At the end, it all depends on what happens when the application scales. How your approach reacts to the growing traffic and then only you get to know the power and importance of microservice architecture.